# Handle tap outside Flutter bottom sheet: show alert dialog instead of closing

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

How can I handle clicking(tapping) outside the bottom sheet in Flutter? If tapped outside the bottom sheet, display an alert dialog instead of closing the sheet. The following code is what I used to show the bottom sheet with text field auto-focus.

Here is my code :

```
_showBottomSheet(ctx)
  {
    Future<void> future =
    showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10.0))),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        context: ctx,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (context) => WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: ()async {print('back arrow pressed'); return true;},
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:18 ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    //onFieldSubmitted: (_){print('feilds submitted');},
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(

                        hintText: 'text field1.',
                        border: InputBorder.none
                        ),
                    autofocus: true,
               
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8.0,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(

                        hintText: 'test field 2',
                        border: InputBorder.none
                    ),
                    autofocus: true,
        
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        child: Icon(Icons.save),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ))
          print('this is then function called after closing bottom sheet');
        });

     
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

make outside tapping disable and use cross button for closing bottomsheet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Play();
  }
}

class Play extends StatefulWidget {
  const Play({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayState createState() => _PlayState();
}

class _PlayState extends State<Play> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TextButton(
        child: Text("call bottom sheet"),
        onPressed: () {
          _showBottomSheet(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

_showBottomSheet(ctx) {
  Future<void> future = showModalBottomSheet(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10.0))),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      context: ctx,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      isDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) => WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
              print('back arrow pressed');
              return true;
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: InkWell(child: Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.red,), onTap: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      //onFieldSubmitted: (_){print('feilds submitted');},
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'text field1.', border: InputBorder.none),
                      autofocus: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8.0,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'test field 2', border: InputBorder.none),
                      autofocus: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('this is then function called after closing bottom sheet');
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: Icon(Icons.save),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ));

}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: thanks Jahidul, I already think of this solution, but unfortunately the business needs handling outside bottom sheet click (tap), if tapped an alert dialog box opened.